# How to turn UTF8 std::string into a NSString?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, utf-8, utf-16

Hello i have a project using both objective-c and c++ , I never set any encoding and on the right panel of the file page it says “no specific encoding set”, but I’ve read that NSString is natively utf-16 so how would I translate a c++ string(utf-8) to NSString(utf-16)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `std::string::data()` method to get access to the raw bytes of the `std::string`. Once you have that, you can use the [`init(bytes:length:encoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407339-init) constructor for `NSString` to convert the raw bytes into a `NSString`. Specify that the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: If I do something like this will the NSString be UTF-8 bit or UTF-16 ? std::string param;
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:param.c_str()];

Comment: NSStrings are always UTF-16; just

Comment: Are we able to use the .data() with NSString and also std::string ? And print it out ?

Comment: .data() is a method of std::string; it just returns a pointer to a char array. You can use it to get the bytes, and then you use the bytes to make the NSString.

Comment: Is there an equivalent method like .data() for NSString ?

Comment: Yes! There’s the cString method

Comment: I called mystring.data() and printed that out it just printed out the string not if it was UTF-8 ?

Comment: I’m confused as to what you’re asking

Comment: @izzyMachado `std::string` has no concept of encodings. It is your responsibility to populate the `std::string` with valid UTF-8 bytes

Comment: That being said, copy-pasting UTF-8 from a web browser etc directly into a string literal works without issues

Comment: Do you know why this still works when we use initWithUTF8String and the string includes non utf8 characters , how is it still able to use the string (if it’s non UTF-8) and print it out with NSLog once it gets to be a NSString ? Also what if my .mm file has not specified a text encoding in the file settings on right pane it says “no specific text encoding specified” does this make a difference ?